# Displaying the schedule with multiple foreach. How to improve code and reduce foreach loops?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, calendar, schedule

I was trying to make a schedule from the database that would look something like this: [image]

I ended up using three loops for displaying. First for showing dates, second to separate every day into rows with overlapping events and third to print out the events in a row.

Before display I had two arrays: `$overlap_array` and `$dates_unique`. `$overlap_array` is the array with resolved rows with events that are overlapping. Here is the little snippet from `$overlap_array`:

```
array (size=7)
0 => 
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => string '2014-04-21' (length=10)
      1 => string '10:00:00' (length=8)
      2 => string '14:00:00' (length=8)
      3 => string '36000' (length=5)
      4 => string '14400' (length=5)
      5 => string 'Listening Cities Presentations Session 1' (length=40)
      6 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => string '2014-04-21' (length=10)
      1 => string '14:00:00' (length=8)
      2 => string '20:30:00' (length=8)
      3 => string '50400' (length=5)
      4 => string '23400' (length=5)
      5 => string 'Listening Cities Presentation 2' (length=31)
      6 => string '2' (length=1)
1 => 
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => string '2014-04-21' (length=10)
      1 => string '15:30:00' (length=8)
      2 => string '17:00:00' (length=8)
      3 => string '55800' (length=5)
      4 => string '5400' (length=4)
      5 => string 'Listening Cities Performance at the DockBar: Part1' (length=50)
      6 => string '3' (length=1)
```

And `$dates_unique` is an array with unique dates in the schedule:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '2014-04-21' (length=10)
  6 => string '2014-04-22' (length=10)
  9 => string '2014-04-23' (length=10)
```

I added Tab.js from Twitter Bootsrap 3 for my tabs. Then I used those arrays to display the schedule inside 3 foreach loops:

```
echo '<div class="tab-content">';
$a = 1;
$class_active = 'tab-pane fade in active';

  foreach ($dates_unique as $dates) {

    echo '<div id="section' . $a . '" class="' . $class_active . '">';
    $a++;
    $class_active = "tab-pane fade";

      foreach ($overlap_array as $row) {

        if ($dates == $row[0][0]) {
        echo '<div class="rows">';

          foreach ($row as $event) {

          $left = ((($event[3] - 36000) / 468)) + 0.1;
          echo '<a href="event/' . $event[6] . '"><div style="width:' .
          (($event[4] / 468) - 0.4) .'%; left: ' . $left . '%;" class="collumn">'.
          $event[5] . ' ' . $event[1] . ' - ' . $event[2] .' '. $event[0] .
          '</div></a>';

          }
          echo '</div>';
        }
      }
      echo '</div>';
  }
  echo '</div>';
```

How could I reduce the number of foreach loops here or maybe I should use another way to display the schedule?

Comment: I don't see a problem here with foreach loops. If they work well and you have no problem with infinite amount of for loops (like in xml parsing) then for me its fine. And for me three loops is not that much. If I had 10 loops in my program or I am out of memory then I would have thought about better solutions. But I understand its working fine.

Comment: OK, thanks. I was just wondering, because when I tried to put those 3 loops into a class method Netbeans were saying that it's better to reduce those blocks and add another method instead. Well, I guess this will work for now :D thanks for the reply.